# Rails save attachment using CloudMailIn and Paperclip to S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip, cloudmailin

I a Rails app that handles Customer Tickets (worequests).  The Tickets have Comments back and forth between the Customer and an Employee.  The Comment can have an attachment.  It's running on Heroku and PaperClip is storing the attachments in S3.

When a new Comment is created and email is sent to both the Customer and the Employee assigned to the Ticket.

I'm using CloudMailIn so that the Customer or Employee can respond to a Comment email with a new Comment.

So far that works fine!

But, I would like to allow the returning email to contain a single attachment.

This is the working incoming mails controller:

```
class IncomingMailsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token

  def create
    Rails.logger.info params
    worequest = params[:envelope][:to].split('@')[0]
    contents = params[:plain].split('---')[0]
    message = Comment.new(
        :worequest_id  => worequest,
        :user_id => User.find_by_email(params[:envelope][:from]).id,
        :comments => contents,
        :tenant_id => 1
    )
    if message.save
      render :text => 'Success', :status => 200
    else
      render :text => message.errors.full_messages, :status => 422, :content_type => Mime::TEXT.to_s
    end
end
```

The log results for `Rails.logger.info params` includes this:

```
"envelope"=>{"to"=>"60@mail.myapp.com", "recipients"=>{"0"=>"60@mail.myapp.com"}, "from"=>"someguy@gmail.com", "helo_domain"=>"mail-wi0-f175.google.com", "remote_ip"=>"xxx.xx.xxx.xxx", "spf"=>{"result"=>"temp_error", "domain"=>"mydomain.com"}}, 

"attachments"=>{"0"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000007194040 @original_filename="five guys.jpeg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"attachments[0]\"; filename=\"five guys.jpeg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20140115-5-1n2rb24>>}, "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"incoming_mails"}
```

attachments is a hash and “0” is the name of the key. `params[:attachments][‘0’]`

I can access these fields fine:

```
Rails.logger.info params[:envelope][:from]
Rails.logger.info params[:envelope][:to]
Rails.logger.info params[:attachments]['0'].original_filename
Rails.logger.info params[:attachments]['0'].content_type
```

But, how do I set the PaperClip `:attach` file?

```
:attach => params[:attachments]['0'].tempfile  ?
:attach => params[:attachments]['0'].read  ?
```

This is my current attempt:

```
attach = Attachment.new(
    :comment_id  => 346,
    :name => "Email Attachment",
    :attach_file_name => params[:attachments]['0'].original_filename,
    :attach_content_type =>  params[:attachments]['0'].content_type,
    :attach => params[:attachments]['0'].path,
    :tenant_id => 1
)
```

The `:attach => params[:attachments]['0'].path,` is wrong.

Getting this:

```
  Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError (No handler found for "/tmp/RackMultipart20140115-13-tcpvtw"):
```

I don't know what to use  ?????

```
:attach => params[:attachments]['0'].read,
:attach => params[:attachments]['0'].path.to_file,
:attach => params[:attachments]['0'].path.read,
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked:

```
        :attach => params[:attachments]['0'],
```

Comment: I had a similar issue, where the official examples would show it as params[:attachments][0] instead of ['0'] ... once I changed that, I could assign things directly, like user.avatar = params[:attachments]["0"]